# How to make "R" use all CPUs

Tags: cpu, r

I am using GNU R to calculate a huge dataset. 
My PC has 4 CPU-cores, and I can see, that R is using only 1 CPU.

Is there a way to tell R to use all 4 CPUs in order to make the calculation complete faster?

Comment: Just to be sure: depending on your code there could be no speedup at all. Having more cores doesn't automatically lead to a performance increase. So, are you sure your code _should_ run faster using more cores?

Comment: @htorque - In the case of Gnu-R, the data crunching is effected a great deal by access to multiple CPU cores. After all it's academic data crunching meant to be running on big iron as well as desktops.

Comment: the calculation contain lots of "for"-loops containing commands for different datasets... I thought that sharing at least these commands to differnt cpu-cores would increase the speed... nevertheless, it is worth a try (as my current calculation-speed will take 5 days to complete!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `r-cran-multicore` package to enable multiple cpu processing:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-multicore
```

See details about this functionality here: http://www.rforge.net/multicore but as a warning, your 'R' code will probably have to be updated to take advantage of multiple core technology. unless you are already using pre-made code which supports the multicore extensions.

Comment: thanks martin, my current script looks something like this:  for(i in length){max(x[i,])} <-- how do I need to change the script in order to use multicore? ("length" and "x" are very large (length>50,000 , x>1700 values in 50,000 rows)

Comment: According to the documentation (linked above) you have to split the job up into parts which are not dependant on each other. In the case of your code, you should endeavour to split it up 4 ways, each loop dealing with 1/4 of the length. How to code this, I don't know in R.

Comment: @Produnis You can easily turn your loops into parallel ones like this: `result <- mclapply(as.data.frame(t(x)), max)`. This example would find by-row maximums using all your CPUs.